# Ruby: mnitest-rails + mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

The instructions for using the mocha mocking library with minitest don't work, and I don't know why...  minitest 4.2.0, minitest-rails 0.3, mocha 0.12.4.  Per the instructions, at the bottom of Gemfile I have

`group :test, :development do
  gem 'mocha', :require => false
end`

which is supposed to turn off auto-requiring.  And then at the bottom of the test helper files, I have `require 'mocha'` - the instructions say `require 'mocha/setup'`, which doesn't even exist.  With these two bits of code in, all the tests that run fine without mocha in the gemfile all fail with "undefined method 'run' blah blah blah".  Anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of mocha works best with minitest. But there was a [recent commit to minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/commit/b3aa6572da3489b381f9b95dfe1f3b9209d57f16) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, apparently those messages are indicative of having failed to install the mocha rails plugin.  That was the problem here.

Comment: I believe its require 'mocha/mini_test' now